# TFS Scheduled backup

Tags: tfs

We are planning to use TFS2013 Scheduled Backups.

Does this back up TFS Analysis DB also? We just use TFS reports and don't use Sharepoint integration

It looks straight forward, Do we need to do anything more rather that setting up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can tell the analysis DB is not available for backup as part of the Scheduled back up, however all of the other databases including TPC's and the TFS_warehouse are, so you can just rebuild your cube after you have restored the warehouse DB.

It is just a matter of creating the schedule and choosing the databases you want to include, and then it just looks after itself and will email you either on Success, Failure or both. just remember that the backup location has to be a network share.